# Software Center says that an app is installed, but when i check it, there is no trace of the package

Tags: ubuntu, apt, software-installation, package-management, dpkg

New Copy of Ubuntu Eoan, and I go to download a game I like to play in my free time from the software center, OpenArena to be exact. I quickly cancel it because I have to go somewhere and don't want to leave the computer on. Once I get back, I notice that Software Center says that it is installed, but when I click *launch*, nothing happens. I then click *remove*, and it says that it is unable to be removed. I try `apt-get purge`, which says its not installed, `apt list`, not installed, `dpkg purge`, not installed. Anything I try says not installed but Software center.

Comment: Did you try installing with `apt-get install openarena`?

Comment: that worked, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Try installing with `apt-get install openarena`